# XSLT match filter checking different nodes in appy-template

Tags: xml, xslt

Not sure if I can filter checking a different node values inside an apply-template in XSLT

I have something like this:

```
    <root>
      <node1>
        <id>001</id>
      </node1>
      <node1>
        <id>003</id>
      </node1>
      <node2>
        <id>001</id>
        <status>A</status>
      </node2>
      <node2>
        <id>001</id>
        <status>T</status>
      </node2>
    </root>
```

I need to apply template to node1 when (node1.id != node2.id) or (node1.id = node2.id and node2.status = A) so when I apply this to check only if id is equal it works:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(node1[not(id= ../node2/id)])"/>
```

But when I try to filter also status in node2 is not working:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(node1[not(id= ../node2[not(status='A')]/id)])"/>
```

Not sure if it can be done in the same line.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion here

Comment: What exactly happens in the case that it "is not working"? Do you get an error? Which one exactly? Or the wrong output? Which result do you want? As there is one `node1` element but there are two `node2` sibling elements it is not quite obvious to me whether you simply want to check all sibling `node2` or only the immediately following one.

Comment: I dont get an error but I dont get the expected result. It can be several node1 and several node2. I need as result of this example apply template for node1 when node1.id != node2.id or node1.id = node2.id and node2.status = 'A', node1 match this condition with node2.id = 001. I can add more nodes to clarify

Comment: I've added a new node1 so  I need to get node1=003 because it not equal to any node2.id and also I need node1=001 because it is equal to node2.id and node2.status = A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `node1[not(id = ../node2/id)] | node1[id = ../node2[status = 'A']/id]`.

Comment: It works! I thought @ it was for attributes but it seems I get the right value. Thank you!

Comment: @Mar, sorry, the `@id` should be `id`.